# Add additional object to variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that may contain objects or may be undefined. I wish to add additional objects to this variable. How do I do that?

code example when applicable:

```
function(){ 
    var comments;
    if(fbposts[fbpost].comments.count){
        for(var comment in fbposts[fbpost].comments.data){
                comments = ({
                    name: fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.name,
                    link: "http://www.facebook.com/"+fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.id,
                    img: "http://www.facebook.com/"+fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.id+"/picture",
                    message: fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].message,
                    created: timeDifference(Date.parse(fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].created_time)),
                })
            }

    }
    return comments;}(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if it is undefined and if so assign it to an empty object:

```
if (typeof yourVar === "undefined")
    yourVar = {};

yourVar.additionalObject1 = { something : "test" };
yourVar.additionalObject2 = { something : "else" };
```

**EDIT**: OK, now that you've added code to your question, it seems like your `comments` variable should be an array, since you are adding to it in a loop. So I think you'd want to do something like this:

```
(function(){ 
    var comments = [];
    if(fbposts[fbpost].comments.count){
        for(var comment in fbposts[fbpost].comments.data){
                comments.push({
                    name: fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.name,
                    link: "http://www.facebook.com/"+fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.id,
                    img: "http://www.facebook.com/"+fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].from.id+"/picture",
                    message: fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].message,
                    created: timeDifference(Date.parse(fbposts[fbpost].comments.data[comment].created_time)),
                });
         }    
    }
    return comments;
})();
```

`comments` will thus contain one element for each comment in your source data. If there are no comments it will be an empty array. (If you want it to return `undefined` if there are no comments then leave the variable declaration where it is as `var comments` and add `comments=[];` just inside the `if` statement.)

Comment: I don't want to name the objects. Is that possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer now that you've added code to your question. I think what you want is for `comments` to be an array.

Comment: Oh, `comments` is an `Array`, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery (and why wouldn't you be?), then you want to look at `$.extend()`

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @KristofferNolgren - If you want jQuery in the answers, you can tag `jQuery` in your question.

Comment: @Derek : just because a question is missing a tag, doesn't mean it might not be a valid part of the answer....